# QML: dynamically add Rectangle to a child of a component instance

Tags: qml

I have an Component that I want to add content to dynamically:

```
MyThing.qml: 

Item{
    Rectangle {
        id: r1
    }
}

main.qml

MyThing {
    id: c1
}
```

In the next line of code in main.qml how would I dynamically add a child rectangle to r1 in c1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to expose `r1` as a property of the root object in `MyThing.qml`, so that it's visible outside of that scope. You can do that using an [`alias`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html):

`MyThing.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property alias rect: r1

    Rectangle {
        id: r1
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Then, you can use [`Qt.createQmlObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) to create the child rectangle, for example:

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    MyThing {
        id: c1
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: {
            Qt.createQmlObject("
                import QtQuick 2.0

                Rectangle {
                    color: \"salmon\"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 10
                }
            ", rect)
        }
    }
}
```

If the child rectangle component exists in a separate file, use [`Qt.createComponent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method).

For a more structured approach, you'd want to use some kind of view, like [`ListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html). The view would take care of creating the child rectangles, and you'd merely control how many should be created (via the [`model`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#model-prop) property, amongst others).